# FXCop warning CA1801: "Parameter is never used..." on overridden inherited supressed property

Tags: interface, properties, fxcop, suppress

On a continued mission to clean up the codebase I inherited, via stylecop and fxcop, and one of the warnings from fxcop was CA1801: Parameter 'value' of Something.MyProperty.set(string) is never used. Remove the parameter or use it in the method body.

The code it complains about is:

```
public class Something : ISomeInterface
    public new string MyProperty
    {
        get
        {
            throw new InvalidOperationException("MyProperty is not implemented.");
        }

        set
        {
            throw new InvalidOperationException("MyProperty is not implemented.");
        }
    }
```

This property is defined in the interface, but in this case is not needed in the derived class - Aside from the slightly questionable use of InvalidOperationException instead of NotImplementedException, which I believe is common, I wonder if I should just exclude the warning in FXCop with a note explaining why?

I don't see what else I could do do in terms of best practice, to prevent the warning in FXCop, other than refactoring this particular property out into a second interface, and then updating all the other classes that use this interface?  I think I may have just answered my own question? :D

Comment: Actually, it's NotSupportedException that should be used in this case.  NotImplementedException is meant to signal that the developer hasn't yet completed the code for a method.  See http://blogs.msdn.com/b/brada/archive/2004/07/29/201354.aspx for details.

Comment: Yes, you are indeed correct there, thanks for that!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I believe it is because of the "new" keyword that you are receiving this warning.  Try <strike>replacing</strike> removing new <strike>with override</strike> and see if the warning disappears.

```
public class Something : ISomeInterface
    public string MyProperty
```

BTW, I recommend using NotImplementedException instead of InvalidOperationException as well.

Comment: Actually, changing it to override did seem to solve it, but not entirely sure I understand why! :D

Comment: In addition, this required the base property to be defined virtual in order to be able to override it.

Comment: @Andrew, Ahh.. sorry I missed this.  Since it is an interface you can just remove new.  New will create another method signature and not implement the interface.